# discord.py not able to delete author messages

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am using Discord.py version 1.0.0. I am trying to write an echo command that, when given a message, will echo the message and delete the command from the chat. Here is an example of my code.

```
client = Bot(description="Test bot", command_prefix="&", pm_help = False)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def echo(ctx):
  await client.send(ctx.message)
  await client.delete_message(ctx.message)
```

The errors I receive tell me that ctx does not have an attribute called "delete_message". I have tried with just delete(). I have looked at others having something of a similar issue, however the solutions did not help me. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In discord.py/rewrite (1.0.0), [Delete is a method on the message](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Message.delete), not on the client. This is the same for every function affecting a message/channel/guild etc.

Instead of doing

```
await client.delete_message(ctx.message)
```

try doing

```
await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on 1.0, you can lose `pass_context` and `client.send` should be `ctx.send`.  You can also write the function signature of the command, using [Keyword-Only Arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments), so that you only echo the message, ignoring the `&echo`

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = Bot(description="Test bot", command_prefix="&", pm_help = False)

@client.command()
async def echo(ctx, *, msg):
  await ctx.send(msg)
  await ctx.message.delete()

client.run('token')
```